# How can I correctly calculate the size(height) of a Scrollbar's grip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To be precise, you guys may have noticed that facebook has this component placed on the right-most column, this is how it would look when the browser window is maximized:
[image: facebook frame (maximized window)]

Now, If I **resize** my browser window to an **smaller** size, this is how it looks:
[image: facebook frame(resized)]

As you can see, as the *overflowing* container re-sizes(because of browser-window re-size), the grip(circled in red) is re-sized too. This to allow scrolling down to the bottom element inside the *over-flowing container*

I have created a similar component using jQuery-Ui:

[image: My frame with scroll(maximized)]

**But my problem is that I haven't been able to calculate the NEW grip size for when the container is resized:**

[image: My frame with scroll(resized)]

Here you can see that I'm *almost* there, but the grip should indeed be smaller to allow scrolling to the bottom (like the Facebook one).

My Question is, **What formula do you suggest using to accomplish this?**

Here's what I've been trying so far:

```
function calculate_grip_size() {
  h = (parseFloat($('#box-container').css('height')) / parseFloat($('#box').css('height'))) * 100;
  $('#grip').css('height', h);
}
```

and the corresponding HTML for it:

```
<div id="box-container">
  <div id="area-track">
    <div id="grip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum... 
    </div>
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum... 
    </div>
    <div class="ipsum">
      Lorem ipsum 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking out this plugin called [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) earlier and the author uses this method - translated to match your selectors (I think); although it would be better to generalize the selectors by using class names instead of IDs:

```
var minH = 50,
    h = Math.max( $('#box-container').outerHeight() / parseInt($('#box').prop('scrollHeight'),10) * 100, minH );
$('#grip').height(h);
```

Update: Oops, bad math and forgot to parse the `scrollHeight` value. Try it now.

Update #2: Ok, I think I found the problem... well two problems.

1. The above calculation didn't take into account that the grip was inside of the area-track which isn't the same height as the box-container

   ```
   $('#grip').height($('#area-track').height() * h);
   ```
2. The content was being positioned as a 1:1 ratio with the grip, so it needed to be divided by the content ratio

   ```
   increment = parseInt(ui.helper.css('top')) / -h;
   ```

And here is a [demo I made](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/dYKFW/) using the code you shared.

Oh, and I had to add `padding-bottom: 25px;` to the `#box` css definition so the whole `ipsum` box was visible - adjust as needed because it depends on how much padding is there.

Comment: :(
As it is, that formula creates an enormous grip(like over 15000px tall). I don't understand the formula quite well, so I wouldn't know what could be missing...

Comment: Sir, It's almost there !; a few notes here; If I don't make the browser window too small it works almost perfect, but it seems the formula starts to fail as the browser window gets smaller, then the grip doesn't shrink enough. Thank you very much nonetheless! If you can investigate further it'd be awesome..

Comment: The `minH` value was added to set a minimum height of the grip, set it to `1` and it should work with smaller heights properly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure If that worked, what I can tell you is that it's still imprecise, meaning that it creates a grip that allows scrolling beyond the size of the content. Maybe the problem lies in how I'm scrolling the content. If you have some time check: https://gist.github.com/1371017    and have a look at the dragGrip function and let me know what you think. Thank you very much, sir !

Comment: Ok, I think I got it... made a demo too

Comment: Wow ! you overwhelm me sir, How could I ever repay you for your time? 
It's always awesome to know there's such a dedicated and friendly community in which one can rely on. This is so awesome ! it works like a charm! and I know many more people will find this question very useful as well! 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

Look at the anatomy of a scrollbar. http://csdgn.org/inform/scrollbar-mechanics

The grip size is usually a `multiplication factor` * `content ratio`. If your content is 200px and the outer box is 100px, then your ratio is 2.0. Once the content gets large enough, the grip size would shrink to very small proportions, so you would want a minimum value for it.

The `multiplication factor` is going to be an arbitrary number of units which you can adjust so that the scrollbar is visually pleasing at all ratios.

Comment: Ok, I have read the article you posted, and let me tell you, It's probably the best resource out there. You're absolutely right about the simplicity of the formula (mult.factor * ratio), that's pretty much it, BUT, If only I could know how to improve the multiplication factor, That'd be the best. As of now it's arbitrary, and it works..let's say 90% ok.
On the other hand, this is one of the cases in which I maybe should just pick a plugin. Do you know a good looking one?
Thanks a LOT for you help!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `.css('height')`, use `.height()`, this returns the calculated height, not the css value.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I think the result was the same. I believe the formula still needs to be overhauled completely. :(